# Deleting folder and its contents: Segmentation fault on <C>

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, delete-file, directory

im having some troubles with this.
I want delete folder and his contents, and i tried with this, but i'm getting Segmentation Fault: 11 and i dont know why, hope you can help me

```
int path_directory (char  *path) {
    struct stat s_buf;

    if (stat(path, &s_buf))
        return 0;

    return S_ISDIR(s_buf.st_mode);
}

void Cmd_delt (char* path[]) {
    DIR*            dp;
    struct dirent*  ep;
    char            *p_buf[2048] = {0};

    dp = opendir(path[0]);
    while ((ep = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        sprintf(*p_buf,"%s/%s", path[0], ep->d_name);
        if (path_directory(*p_buf))
        {
            Cmd_delt(p_buf);

        }

        else
            unlink(*p_buf);

    }

    closedir(dp);
    remove(path[0]);
}
```

Comment: its only a piece of the  code

Comment: one which i have no way of testing

Comment: suggesting, output the command instead of running it until you have everything right... in case you accidentally delete `/`

Comment: thanks for the advice!

Comment: Your edit rendered the question completely meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an array of pointers to `char` to store the result of `sprintf`, you need room for a string (an array of `char`'s is enough):

```
char *p_buf[2048] = {0};
```

should be

```
char p_buf[2048] = {0};
```

and

```
    sprintf(*p_buf,"%s/%s", path[0], ep->d_name);
```

should be

```
    sprintf(p_buf,"%s/%s", path[0], ep->d_name);
```

Same for

```
void Cmd_delt (char* path[]) {
```

your `path` should be a string (not an array of strings)

change to:

```
void Cmd_delt (char *path) {
```

and use `path` instead of `path[0]`.

Comment: Didnt work, i get this Warning error shell.c:85:22: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char [2048]' to
      parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            Cmd_delt(p_buf);
                     ^~~~~
and when i try to execute it fails again with the same error

Comment: Edited, aldo change `void Cmd_delt (char* path[]) {` to  `void Cmd_delt (char* path) {` if you want to pass a path as string.

Comment: It keeps giving me Segmentation fault.. :(

Comment: Ok, so now i think the fail is on the recursive call of the function Cmd_delt, so something is failing when i call him after the first interaction.

Comment: If you give me your mail, i can send you all the code, is not very long and you can test it. i think that is better than make a minimal test. (if you want, obviously)

Comment: If it's not very long paste-it here ;)

Comment: @GilbertoPlaza: Changing your application-with-a-problem into a MCVE-still-with-the-problem is actually a time-honored debugging technique. Doing it before asking the internet for help is self-educating, and will make you a better programmer (and debugger) in the long run.